# How to cancel the middle mouse button back button?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse, website

I have a mouse so I don't have to press the back button on Google Chrome. Sometimes, I'm a bit fidgety or I just accidentally hold down the middle mouse button. When I want to cancel it, I usually press Winkey + D to go to the desktop and then I let go of the mouse button so that I don't go back to the previous website. However, I want to know if there is any easier way to cancel the back button.

Thanks.

Comment: In Windows this can be done with a custom program: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-reassign-mouse-buttons-8012f6b3-3b63-fd3f-39f0-30fde318db09 But it's extremely limited to only Microsoft hardware :(

Answer (score 0):

I found [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remap-mouse-buttons-on-windows-10/) this does the job for me.